# jquery unbind is not instantaneous

Tags: jquery, unbind

On the mousemove event i bound a serie of fadeIn/fadeOut functions to an component like this :

```
 $( "#cropshiftbundle" ).bind( "mousemove", function() {                                
       $("#cropimgbtn").fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200);
 });
```

then on a click event, i unbound the mouseover event like this :

```
  $("#cropimgbtn").click(function(){            
      $("#cropshiftbundle").unbind("mousemove");  
  });
```

Well, i know that the unbind happens instantaneousely, but it seems that it still a serie of fadeIn/fadeOut that were triggered already and will affect the component whatever the unbind happens or not..(i dont know if this is the truth..) therefore the unbind looks not instantaneous..
So, what can be done to stop eveything just when the unbind happens ?
Cheers!

Comment: Really, that looks like a good idea, binding an event that fires hundreds of times every second to a function that queues four animations on every single pixel the mouse moves ?

Comment: isn't that what actually happens ? :)

Comment: he meant that is a very bad idea..

Answer (score 1):

Try [.stop(true,true)](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

> Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

```
$("#cropimgbtn").stop(true,true)
$("#cropshiftbundle").off("mousemove");
```

and better use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Answer (score 1):

It is because there will be still queued animations in the `fx` queue, you can use .stop() to clear the queue, but keep in mind that the current animation will finish

```
$("#cropimgbtn").stop(true,true);
$("#cropshiftbundle").off("mousemove");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PjCkr/)